# Emulator in Android Studio's AVD won't start correctly

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, android-emulator

I'm setting up a Flutter environment and all except my emulator isn't working.

I'm using Android Studio 3.6.2

This is the setup for the emulator in AVD:

[image]

Virtualization is enabled and HAXM is installed

[image]

[image]

[image]

When launching the emulator it only gets to about where the red square is, then does nothing and returns to the virtual devices list:
[image]

Also tried launching it with flutter itself by command line and in VS Code with no luck:
[image]

[image]

And I don't get any error messages.

Anyone know where to go from here?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried setting up a different emulator?

Comment: what happens when you change nothing of the emulator settings when you are creating the emulator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After creating AVD from android studio. Open `Command Prompt` and execute this command.

```
C:\Path_to_Android_Sdk\sdk\tools\emulator.exe -netdelay none -netspeed full -avd YOUR_AVD_DEVICE_NAME
```

Comment: This helped me get an error message, the problem was not enough disk space, after freeing up space the emulator ran with the command you provided, it didn't upon trying to launch it from AVD though. Regardless I will mark this as accepted.